# Cortana cannot hear me - But my microphone works fine everywhere else

Tags: microphone, windows-10, cortana

I'm having a really unique issue with Cortana not being able to hear me. I was able to set her up just fine when I did 'Learn My Voice' underneath her settings. When I click the microphone next to the Search Bar, she doesn't recognize anything I'm saying. It seems there is a second 'Set up Microphone' underneath Cortana that, when asked to read the 'Peter' sentence, doesn't appear to hear me.

My headset is a Razer Chimaera 7.1. All of my applications such as Skype, Ventrilo, etc. work just fine after moving from Windows 7 to Windows 10. The microphone displays just fine under 'Sound' -> 'Recording Devices' and the bar moves up and down to confirm it's picking up my voice.

**Things I've tried:**

- From 'Sound' -> 'Recording Devices' I did 'Set up Microphone' and read the 'Peter' sentence and it picks it up just fine. However, this does not translate over to Cortana and it still requires a second 'Set up Microphone' which still doesn't work.
- Switching from the motherboard microphone port to the front port and vice versa
- Restarting
- Reinstalling Windows 10
- I have tried a different microphone that is less robust and **Cortana picks me up just fine.** However, it's not preferable to the one I'm using now.

Answer (score 1):

Go into settings>change sound card settings>recordings>choose your mic>go into levels and slide the volume to the needed level. This worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Thanks for answering, though. Hopefully it works for others!

Comment: This worked for me. Hence, the thumbs up. :)

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned solutions doesn't work for me, but following does:

1. Right-click on the sound icon in the taskbar, and go to `Recording devices`
2. Double-click on your `default microphone`
3. Go to `Enhancements`, and check `Disable all sound effects` (*seems like in oldest version of windows 10 the option is `Disable all enhancements`*)

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if the mic is set to give applications exclusive access.

Sound > Recording Devices > right click microphone > properties > advanced tab > deselect allow applications to take exclusive control of this device.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Maybe it'll work for someone else. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

> Go into settings>change sound card settings>recordings>choose your mic>go into levels and slide the volume to the needed level. This worked for me.

This is a good suggestion to see if the mic levels are set correctly. However, **there may be a simple solution to this.** Go into Windows Update, Check for Updates and install any updates available. This worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Thanks for answering, though. Hopefully it works for others!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy?

I have the same problem and cortana was working before i started using a proxy.

I would try disabling your proxy settings.
It fixed it for me!

Your computer may also be auto detecting a proxy, you could disable that too.

Comment: I wasn't using a proxy at the time.

Comment: Ok I have no clue then. My answer will stay here because it fixed it for me.