# Cortana can't hear me, but responds to "Hey Cortana"

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I can turn Cortana on by saying "Hey Cortana". She appears to listen but ignores everything. After a few seconds she says she didn't hear anything. This problem appeared on both of my computers at the same time. What could possibly cause this?

Everything about the microphones is fine and there is no proxy. There is an SSH tunnel at some point in the network, but it worked fine before.

My 2.5 year old son spent some time talking to her the day before she broke down. I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but he has broken things I had thought were unbreakable before. I checked the settings, but they seem to be the same. I went through "Learn how I say Hey Cortana" routine again successfully but it didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cortana cannot hear me - But my microphone works fine everywhere else](https://superuser.com/questions/947649/cortana-cannot-hear-me-but-my-microphone-works-fine-everywhere-else)

Answer (score 0):

I connected using IP from another country and Cortana heard me. Then went back to my original IP, which is static, and she kept on working. It also unblocked the other computer on the network, which has the same static IP, even though I didn't do anything there. I'm guessing my son talking nonsense to her for half an hour triggered some security mechanism that blocked my IP, which is also from a Digital Ocean IP pool (the network is SSHed through a Digital Ocean server). That might have also raised a flag somewhere. It's all my guesses though.